# Using putty in a Linux environment how do I view Windows files

Tags: linux, putty

When I enter the putty shell, it gives me a default path [ec2-user@ip-10-79-141-32 ~]$. If the file I am trying to run is on the desktop, how do I be sure that I CD to the desktop? Also I am using linux to search for my windows files

Comment: Putty is connecting to a shell on a different computer which has no access to the files on your local computer.

Comment: I guess my question is, what do I need to do to make sure that I can test a file that is stored on a Windows OS to work on a Lunix OS (Using putty)

Comment: You need to copy the file to the linux computer. Look at scp

Comment: I am running a linux server using putty (On a windows machine)

Answer (score 0):

Use a software Winscp. You can transfer files from Linux ENV to Windows ENV and wise-versa.